# OnListItemClick event not working

Tags: android, listactivity

I have been facing a problem...there is a five different Java classes MainActivity, Application, ApplicationAdapter, FetchData ,FetchDataListener.. I am binding mysql data from api in ListView... but I am trying to fire a click event on ListView but I am getting error....here is code...

MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
public void onFetchComplete(List<Applicity> data) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
    // create new adapter
    ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
    // set the adapter to list
    setListAdapter(adapter);        
}
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Applicity app= new Applicity();
    int p =app.getPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(this,p,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

ApplicationAdapter.java

```
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Applicity>{
private List<Applicity> items;

public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, List<Applicity> items) {
    super(context, R.layout.app_custom_list, items);
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if(v == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.app_custom_list, null);            
    }

    Applicity app = items.get(position);

    if(app != null) {
        ImageView icon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.appIcon);
        TextView titleText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
        LinearLayout ratingCntr = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.ratingCntr);
        TextView dlText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dlTxt);

        if(icon != null) {
            Resources res = getContext().getResources();
            String sIcon = "com.sj.jsondemo:drawable/" + app.getIcon();
            icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(res.getIdentifier(sIcon, null, null)));
        }

        if(titleText != null) titleText.setText(app.getTitle());

        if(dlText != null) {
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
            dlText.setText(nf.format(app.getTotalDl())+" dl");            
        }

        if(ratingCntr != null && ratingCntr.getChildCount() == 0) {        
            /*
             * max rating: 5
             */
            for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
                ImageView iv = new ImageView(getContext());

                if(i <= app.getRating()) {
                    iv.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.start_checked));
                }
                else {                
                    iv.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.start_unchecked));
                }

                ratingCntr.addView(iv);
            }
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

}

Applicity.java

```
public class Applicity {
private String title;
private long totalDl;
private int rating;
public int position;
private String icon;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public long getTotalDl() {
    return totalDl;
}
public void setTotalDl(long totalDl) {
    this.totalDl = totalDl;
}
public int getRating() {
    return rating;
}
public void setRating(int rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}
public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}
public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}
public int getPosition(int arg){
    return position;
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your error from Logcat :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24331855/3571822 duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Use OnItemClickListener. You're creating a new custom method instead of OnItemClickListener.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Do something here. 
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Sahil ! I have to get the row data on row click thats why I used OnListItemClick. Is there any other alternative to get data on row click instead of item click.

Comment: It is the complete row itself that is the 'item' here. Just try to use the OnItemClickListener as illustrated above, it will definitely work. Once you get the row position in the listener function, you can query all 'internal objects related to that row' viz title, rating, dl in your case.

Comment: Thanks dear ! its working now but after adding getListView();